# How to get memory details of internet explorer and Firefox tabs?

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-studio, memory-management

I need to see whether the tabs are idle and get memory details of each tab from C#/C++ or C.I did it for Chrome as each tab has unique process.But how can I do this for Internet Explorer and Firefox tabs? I need to get memory used by each tab and identify the idle tabs as well.Please advice

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the about: memory page in Firefox.  However it may not be very easy to access externally.  In recent Firefox versions I believe the about:memory page has the ability to dump memory information to a file.  This would probably be a good start.

An alternate option would probably be to write a plugin or add on to accomplish your task.

Nicholas Nethercote has a great blog about memory related aspects of Firefox.  It's hosted on blog.Mozilla.org. well worth a look for additional resources.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is not much information in the blog about about:memory can you suggest me any links on how to use it in C#?

Comment: Perhaps something like http://docs.seleniumhq.org/ would help you?  It has a .NET interface so could work.  Past that you're probably on your own.